# Android App is not installable from Play Store in spite of targeting the right SDK. Why?

Tags: android, sdk, android-gradle-plugin, publish, android-7.1-nougat

Here is my Gradle file without the dependencies;

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxx.yyy"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.1"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

The App is published on the Play Store, but says "This app is incompatible with your device." on the web and doesn't show in search results on the mobile Play Store. When I push from Android Studio, of course, it runs on the phone.

Also, I am only using two basic permissions for this app. Do I have to do anything else? In the previous version (1) of this app, I had targeted SDK 19 and it was throwing the incompatibility error. So, I changed to 27, built and tested again, then uploaded. Now, I still get the same error. The app status is "Published" now. Could this be a bug on Play Store?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Please help. Thanks!

Comment: When I push (build and run) directly from Android Studio, of course, it runs on the phone. So, what are you implying?

Comment: Are u publishing the app for the firstime? did any filters in google play restrict the app to showup?

Comment: In the previous version (1) of this app, I had targeted SDK 19 and it was throwing the incompatibility error. So, I changed to 27, built and tested again, then uploaded. Now, I still get the same error. The app status is "Published" now. Could this be a bug on Play Store? No, no filters, it just doesn't show on mobile under my store. On web, I see it, but it says incompatible.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html  in manifest you can support sdk versions, screen size etc   <uses-sdk />
    <uses-configuration />  
    <uses-feature />  
    <supports-screens />  
    <compatible-screens />  
    <supports-gl-texture />

Comment: What are you saying @Pomagranite? How does that fix my issue?

Comment: If the problem is  "This app is incompatible with your device." then changing manifest entries on what devices the app supports could help. Granted you would then have to implement support for those devices but it is a start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went to my developer console, Release Management->Artifact Library, clicked on the small info button next to my release. It said "Supported Devices: 0". I was horrified. 
I went to my app, removed a Java IOUtils library that wasn't needed in my code. Then there was a warning during build about a WebView feature that wasn't needed (which was only for older SDKs), I removed that. Then added an action.VIEW intent filter to one of the activities. Then, I made minimum SDK 16 instead of 15. Then I changed the dependecies;

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
```

As of writing this, this was the latest available. Then, cleaned it, built app, tested again. 
Then, I updated the version code and version name, generated another signed APK.
I uploaded version 1.2. Waited for a while.

Now, it shows multiple supported devices from SDK 16 to 27. I still don't know what fixed it. Thanks Google.

Regards